# Percentage with borders

Tags: html, css

There is a way to make `.teste` with 100% width (150px)?

```
<div class='debug'>
    <div class='debug'>
        <div class='teste'>Hello world!</div>
    </div>
</div>

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.debug {
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.teste {
  /* width: 150px; */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxbwv62L/

The computed size is 148px. Why isn't it 150px?

Comment: Change it to `box-sizing: content-box;`?

Comment: borders... if you want the div to be 150px without borders calculated you need to take box-sizing: border-box out.

Comment: But then I'll have problems in other divs...

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using `box-sizing: border-box`. That makes it so `.debug` width stays at `150px` and has the border go inside the div. So the remaining width for `.teste` is only `148px`. If you want to keep both widths at `150px` then you can switch around the properties like this:

```
.debug {
  width: 150px;
}

.teste {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gddnwfkm/)

Comment: Thanks! But following this, I can't have nested divs with borders. This is correct?

Comment: nested inside `.debug`? yeah i guess that's true

Answer (score 0):

Give `.teste` a negative left and right margin of the border-size (`1px` in this case).

```
.teste {
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Comment: This is too specific, I would like a more general solution. Thanks anyway